# Exchange 2010 user mail is autoforwarding, but autoforwarding is not setup

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Really confused here, we use Exchange 2010 and one of our users (call them Alice) is having all their mail auto-forwarded to another user (call them Bob).

Alice has no rules set up at all and looking at the Exchange Management console, there is no auto-forwarding set up on her mailbox.

I ran this PowerShell:

```
get-mailbox -Identity Alice@domain.tld | select-object Name, ForwardingAddress
```

And it showed no ForwardingAddress. I ran another one:

```
$mbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity Alice@domain.tld; $mbox | Foreach {Get-Inbox Rule -Mailbox $_}
```

And the only rule that was there was the "Clear categories on mail" one.

I am entirely stumped by this one as those are the only two places I know of that have anything to do with auto-forwarding messages.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Journaling would also pull a copy of the messages.

Comment: Get-MessageTrackingLog would also likely be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The first question has to be whether the user has wanted to forward their email to this other user in the past.

If so, can the user remember how they set it up?

I would be looking at delegates, and possibly resetting the rules engine within Outlook - Exchange doesn't always show all of the rules, particularly if you have a corrupt one.

Answer (score 0):

If the sender of the auto-forwarded email is Alice while the recipient is Bob, then it IS from Alice's mailbox to Bob's mailbox. In this situation, [use the MFCMAPI to check or clear the mailbox rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hkong/2015/02/27/how-to-delete-corrupted-hidden-inbox-rules-from-a-mailbox-using-mfcmapi/).

Also, ensure the affected user's Outlook is not running, then send a test email to her, see if the message will be forwarded to Bob. If not, maybe the Outlook add-in causes the issue. Running Outlook in safe mode(Running Outlook.exe /safe), or manually disable add-ins to find the one causing this issue.

If the sender of the auto-forwarded email is not Alice but the original sender, it would be another story. Search the [message tracking log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926(v=exchg.141).aspx) and [pipeline trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/bb125018(v=exchg.141).aspx) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, turns out that Alice had set a rule within her Out-Of-Office message that auto-forwarded all the mail to Bob. I didn't even know you could set up Out-Of-Office rules so never thought to look there.

Of course I figured this out after they came back and disabled their Out-Of-Office...